# ADB shell running multiple commands in a row fails

Tags: adb

in the adb command i run is `adb -s 127.0.0.1:21503 shell \"su cat /data/data/org.telegram.messenger/files/cache4.db\"` get error `/system/bin/ sh: su cat /data/data/org.telegram.messenger/files/cache4.db: not found` which when I run each command again it works

**As I run each command**

```
adb -s 127.0.0.1:21503 shell
su
cat /data/data/org.telegram.messenger/files/cache4.db
```

*Result for  **As I run each command**: always show cache4.db file data to the screen*

Comment: did any of the answers below help to figure out the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can try: `adb -s 127.0.0.1:21503 shell "cat /data/data/org.telegram.messenger/files/cache4.db"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command:

```
adb -s 127.0.0.1:21503 shell "su; cat /data/data/org.telegram.messenger/files/cache4.db"
```

So the semicolon between `su` and `cat` command allows to execute them subsequently.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
adb -s 127.0.0.1:21503 shell su -c "cat /data/data/org.telegram.messenger/files/cache4.db"
```